# Incorporating Merge Module (MSM) into ClickOnce package

Tags: clickonce

First off my background for many years has been building and deploying Web Applications and it has been a long while since I've done any heavy Windows Forms Application Development.

I have a task to deploy a large Windows Forms solution using ClickOnce.  Amongst other things I am working through such as Registration Free COM etc I have a number of Merge Modules which are traditionally merged with the application in the Installer Project.

I am trying to find guidance/information on how to achieve the same with ClickOnce deployment.  The best solution I've found so far would be to try and build individual MSI projects for each Merge Module and then add them as a pre-requisite, to me this doesn't seem clean or ideal.

Has anyone incoporated a Merge Module into a ClickOnce Application Publication?  If so do you know of any good documentation please?

Thanks

Andrew